# Change Graph.db location on Neo4j Docker to local file

Tags: docker, neo4j, spark-streaming, boot2docker

I have been following this tutorial [www.kennybastani.com](http://www.kennybastani.com/2015/03/spark-neo4j-tutorial-docker.html)  I am looking to integrate my NEo4j database with the Dockerized version described in the tutorial. The Dockerized version provides an interface between Neo4j and Spark GraphX. I am new to Docker.

Steps taken:

1. `export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://$(boot2docker ip 2>/dev/null):2375`
2. `$(boot2docker shelling)`
3. `docker run  --env DOCKER_HOST=$DOCKER_HOST \
                 --env DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=$DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY \
                 --env DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/docker/cert \
                 -v $DOCKER_CERT_PATH:/docker/cert \
                 -ti kbastani/spark-neo4j up -d`
4. At this point I have no issues running Neo4j in the container and as a test I imported the demo dataset: `:play movies`

**5. I want to change the location of the dockerized Graph.db to my local one.**

*Attempt 1:*

I tried running the container with:

`docker run  --env DOCKER_HOST=$DOCKER_HOST \
              --env DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=$DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY \
              --env DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/docker/cert \
              —v /usr/local/Cellar/neo4j/3.0.3/libexec/data/databases/graph.db:opt/data \
              -ti kbastani/spark-neo4j up -d`

The réponse I get is: `docker: Error parsing reference: "—v" is not a valid repository/tag.` I also tried with `--volume <path-here>`

*Attempt 2:*

1. Logged into the container and opened: `neo4j-server.properties`
2. Edit `org.neo4j.server.database.location=opt/data` to point to my local Graph.db.

Unfortunately, no luck with either solution.

*Background:*

I am looking to implement k-means streaming in Apache Spark to cluster bitcoin transactions in realtime. The stack is involves, Neo4j, Spark, Flask.

Answer (score 0):

The -v in your text above doesn't look like the same - as in the -ti.  Try retyping it (it may have unicode in it that's causing issues).  Also, do just physical_path:/data as the location, and you could even type out --volume=physical_path:/data

Comment: After following your suggestion (thanks), I get this response: `app_graphdb_1 is up-to-date` however the library still points to: `/var/lib/neo4j-community-2.2.3/opt/data` and my local data does not appear in the neo4j browser app.

Comment: Ok, I think I see the issue; where you have your path to the local data there should likely not be the databases subdir.  If you look in the data dir you might see another data/databases directory with a fresh graph.db.  Here's what I have in mine:  $HOME/neo4j/data:/data.  That puts the databases subdir in the data dir.

Comment: Not seeing any changes, when i run `docker inspect` I see: `"Mounts": [
            {
                "Name": "eab6aad4fd3da5196098e91836b17c7db2fe5dba397bd779a885af7d3bb4686a",
                "Source": "/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/volumes/eab6aad4fd3da5196098e91836b17c7db2fe5dba397bd779a885af7d3bb4686a/_data",
                "Destination": "/opt/data",` which doesn't seem right

Comment: did you mount the host folder to the VritualBox VM and then mount that location to boot2docker?